# Mysql 8 user length issue in centos 8

Tags: mysql

I tried the create a mysql user , length of user name 23 . It failed . I am user mysql 8 on centos 8 .
Just I tested my create user script by  different user name ( less than 16) . It work .
Can anyone advise How I can increase the default user name length.

[image]

Comment: You are trying to create a user table in the mysql data base? - is that wise?

Comment: Please share more details, like the commands involved in text form

Comment: No , I am not creating user in mysql schema , I just show mysql.user table for user column  field. That create commend ran on different schema .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the manual

> MySQL user names are up to 32 characters long. Operating system user names may have a different maximum length

And also:

Warning

The MySQL user name length limit is hardcoded in MySQL servers and clients, and trying to circumvent it by modifying the definitions of the tables in the mysql database does not work.

> You should never alter the structure of tables in the mysql database in any manner whatsoever except by means of the procedure that is described in Section 2.11, “Upgrading MySQL”. Attempting to redefine MySQL's system tables in any other fashion results in undefined and unsupported behavior. The server is free to ignore rows that become malformed as a result of such modifications.

Read more [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-names.html)

Comment: Issue is resolved . Actually  it is my mistake. User already exist . That's why I got that error . On my application , It is having huge list of user , unfortunately , I did not verify the user exist or not .